# How can i comment command line arguments on multiple lines?

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script with nice comments on all arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

command \
  # this is important because ..
  -flag arg \
  # this is also important b/c ..
  --other-option \
  # etc..
```

The backslash only escapes the newline before the comment tho, so `-flag arg` is treated as a new command.

Comment: I usually put comments like this in my "usage" for the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mattyice has a good suggestion.

An alternative approach is to stick the command in an array to reduce the noise overhead of commenting. This also allows printing the command in such a way that it can easily be reissued outside of the script:

```
cmd=(
  tar

  # Extract a named, gzipped file
    xzf "$file"

  # Ignore the leading directory
    --strip-components=1
)

# Optionally print the command in copy-pasteable format
echo "Executing: "
printf "%q " "${cmd[@]}"
echo

# Execute the command:
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Any piping or redirections would go on the execution line, not in the array.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for are "inline comments".  You can mimic these with the backtick (`) and ending the line with a slash (\) like so:

```
echo \
  `# this is a comment` \
  -e 'duuuuddddee!!!'
```

As noted in the comments, there is some overhead with this solution

Comment: Does this fork a shell to execute each comment?

Comment: yes technically there is some overhead in this solution